# Is there any way to know when the standard cancel button is clicked in lightning after calling e.force:editRecord

Tags: lightning, lightning-events

I want to do some modification when standard cancel button is clicked in lightning..Is there any event or any other way to get that?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using lightning recordeditform?

Comment: Yes there are different scenarios. Standard cancel button firing event is needed.

Comment: If there is any event which notify if any modal is closed or not?

Comment: with a recordEditForm component you can add your cancel button method and you can embed the form in a modal using the overlay library, it will give you the flexibility you need.